# How to store Java Date to Mysql datetime with JPA

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, jpa

Can any body tell me how can I store Java Date to Mysql datetime...?

When I am trying to do so...only date is stored and time remain 00:00:00
in Mysql date stores like this...

```
2009-09-22 00:00:00
```

I want not only date but also time...like

```
2009-09-22 08:08:11
```

I am using JPA(Hibernate) with spring mydomain classes uses java.util.Date but i have created tables using handwritten queries...

this is my create statement

```
CREATE TABLE ContactUs (
  id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  userName VARCHAR(30), 
  email VARCHAR(50),
  subject VARCHAR(100), 
  message VARCHAR(1024), 
  messageType VARCHAR(15), 
  contactUsTime DATETIME,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Comment: pieces of your code, perhaps?

Comment: link :
http://www.coderanch.com/t/304851/JDBC/java/Java-date-MySQL-date-conversion

Comment: These days you should no longer be using `java.util.Date` at all (in 2010 there probably was no better choice). Better to use the modern classes, like `java.time.Instant` or `java.time.LocalDateTime`, depending on the exact requirements for the date-time you need to store.

Comment: Some of these old answers comeup pretty high on Google rankings. In Java 8+ we can simply use LocalDateTime to save datetime instead of resorting to using @Temporal to save in datetime format

Comment: preparedStatement.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));

Answer (score 170, accepted):

see in the link :

http://www.coderanch.com/t/304851/JDBC/java/Java-date-MySQL-date-conversion

The following code just solved the problem:

```
java.util.Date dt = new java.util.Date();

java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = 
     new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

String currentTime = sdf.format(dt);
```

This '**currentTime**' was inserted into the column whose type was DateTime and it was successful.

Comment: but,currentTime is a String object, and in db we take datetime as datatype,i think it is not going to be inserted.right?

Comment: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` is very important. Take note of the capitalization.

Answer (score 98):

Annotate your field (or getter) with `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)`, like this:

```
public class MyEntity {
    ...
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private java.util.Date myDate;
    ...
}
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: This is the answer indeed!

Comment: up for this, this is the proper answer.

Comment: be aware that if you choose this solution, your date will appear as a timestamp when fetched from db. It won't have the nice formatting 'yyyy-MM-dd....')

Answer (score 38):

Are you perhaps using `java.sql.Date`? While that has millisecond granularity as a Java class (it is a subclass of `java.util.Date`, bad design decision), it will be interpreted by the JDBC driver as a date without a time component. You have to use `java.sql.Timestamp` instead.

Comment: I wouldn't use `java.sql.Date` or `java.sql.Timestamp` in domain classes but I guess this was written before the edit of the OP.

Comment: I would. java.util.Date objects don't compare to java.sql.Timestamp objects with entirely predictable results.

Answer (score 7):

Probably because your java date has a different format from [`mysql format`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) (`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`)

do this

```
 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
 Date date = new Date();
 System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

Comment: You mentioned the correct format in the reference and then used the wrong format in the code.

Answer (score 6):

you will get 2011-07-18 + time format

```
long timeNow = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
java.sql.Timestamp ts = new java.sql.Timestamp(timeNow);
...
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(TIME_COL_INDEX, ts);
```

Answer (score 5):

mysql datetime -> GregorianCalendar

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = format.parse("2012-12-13 14:54:30"); // mysql datetime format
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.setTime(date);
System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
```

GregorianCalendar -> mysql datetime

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String string = format.format(calendar.getTime());
System.out.println(string);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
java.util.Date date = new Date();
Object param = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());    
preparedStatement.setObject(param);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to insert the date into MySQL. Instead of changing our date's format to meet MySql's requirement, we can help data base to recognize our date by setting the `STR_TO_DATE(?, '%l:%i %p')` parameters.

For example, 2014-03-12 can be represented as `STR_TO_DATE('2014-03-12', '%Y-%m-%d')`

```
preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test.msft VALUES (default, STR_TO_DATE( ?, '%m/%d/%Y'), STR_TO_DATE(?, '%l:%i %p'),?,?,?,?,?)");
```

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple though conditions in this answer are in mysql the **column datatype is datetime** and you want to send data from java code to mysql:

**java.util.Date dt = new java.util.Date();

`whatever your code object may be`.setDateTime(dt);**

> important thing is just pick the date and its format is already as per mysql format and send it, no further modifications required.

Answer (score 1):

If using **java 8 or higher** , try to use **LocalDateTime**. That was the correct type if you are using **DATETIME** as mysql data type.

Below is example for conver current time to "2009-09-22 08:08:11" format

```
LocalDateTime currentTime = LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.now().toString(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you may not use SimpleDateFormat, you can use something like this;

```
  @JsonSerialize(using=JsonDateSerializer.class)
  @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
  private Date blkDate;
```

This way you can directly get the date with format as specified.

Answer (score 0):

I still prefer the method in  one line

```
new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())
```

Answer (score -2):

it works for me !!

in mysql table

```
DATETIME
```

in entity:

```
private Date startDate;
```

in process:

```
objectEntity.setStartDate(new Date());
```

in preparedStatement:

```
pstm.setDate(9, new java.sql.Date(objEntity.getStartDate().getTime()));
```