# Handling MySQL datetimes and timestamps in Java

Tags: java, mysql, date, jdbc, timestamp

In a java application what would a good compromise in terms of extracing and inputting date information with a MySQL database using a mix of datetimes and timestamps?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

In Java side, the date is usually represented by the (poorly designed, but that aside) [`java.util.Date`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). It is basically backed by the [Epoch time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_time) in flavor of a `long`, also known as a timestamp. It contains information about both the date and time parts. In Java, the precision is in milliseconds.

In SQL side, there are several standard date and time types, `DATE`, `TIME` and `TIMESTAMP` (at some DB's also called `DATETIME`), which are represented in JDBC as [`java.sql.Date`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html), [`java.sql.Time`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html) and [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html), all *subclasses* of `java.util.Date`. The precision is DB dependent, often in milliseconds like Java, but it can also be in seconds.

In contrary to `java.util.Date`, the `java.sql.Date` contains only information about the date part (year, month, day). The `Time` contains only information about the time part (hours, minutes, seconds) and the `Timestamp` contains information about the both parts, like as `java.util.Date` does.

The normal practice to store a timestamp in the DB (thus, `java.util.Date` in Java side and `java.sql.Timestamp` in JDBC side) is to use [`PreparedStatement#setTimestamp()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp%28int,%20java.sql.Timestamp%29).

```
java.util.Date date = getItSomehow();
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE ts > ?");
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(1, timestamp);
```

The normal practice to obtain a timestamp from the DB is to use [`ResultSet#getTimestamp()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp%28int%29).

```
Timestamp timestamp = resultSet.getTimestamp("ts");
java.util.Date date = timestamp; // You can just upcast.
```

Comment: do you think that using java.sql.Timestamp in the model (Java layer) is bad?

Comment: @cherouvim: Yes. The model shouldn't be aware of any JDBC specifics. Only use it to set the timestamp. `preparedStatement.setTimestamp(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));`. Getting it is easy since it's already a subclass of `java.util.Date`.

Comment: This will work fine if all your machines and users are in the same timezone. Otherwise, beware the MySQL JDBC driver's handling of timezone conversions  is incredibly complex and buggy. For example see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40670532/what-are-jdbc-mysql-driver-settings-for-sane-handling-of-datetime-and-timestamp/40681941#40681941

Comment: BalusC, what type should I use then for a column inside DB in your opinion (Date/Timestamp?). Following your example I receive something like 2017-01-24 19:17:11.0 when I read from DB, but before it was Tue Jan 24 19:17:11 EET 2017. Moreover, when I compare using compareTo, I get: before > after. P.S. I use timestamp in DB

Comment: @Sabine: You have a timestamp with timezone. This is not supported by all DBs. E.g. PostgreSQL and Oracle do, but MySQL not. You'd need to convert to a fixed timezone before saving in DB. Usually UTC is used.

Answer (score 9):

The MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html) has information on mapping MySQL types to Java types. In general, for MySQL datetime and timestamps you should use `java.sql.Timestamp`. A few resources include:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

http://www.coderanch.com/t/304851/JDBC/java/Java-date-MySQL-date-conversion

[How to store Java Date to Mysql datetime...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400955/how-to-store-java-date-to-mysql-datetime)

http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t599436-the-best-practice-to-deal-with-datetime-in-mysql-using-jdbc.html

EDIT:

As others have indicated, the suggestion of using strings may lead to issues.

Comment: why would it better to convert the dates into strings?

Comment: Don't massage it forth and back as string. It's recipe for portability and maintainability trouble.

Comment: Agreed. I've modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

BalusC gave a good description about the problem but it lacks a good end to end code that users can pick and test it for themselves.

Best practice is to always store date-time in UTC timezone in DB.
Sql timestamp type does not have timezone info.

When writing datetime value to sql db

```
    //Convert the time into UTC and build Timestamp object.
    Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC")));
    //use setTimestamp on preparedstatement
    preparedStatement.setTimestamp(1, ts);
```

When reading the value back from DB into java,

1. Read it as it is in java.sql.Timestamp type.
2. Decorate the DateTime value as time in UTC timezone using atZone
   method in LocalDateTime class.
3. Then, change it to your desired timezone. Here I am changing it to
   Toronto timezone.

   ```
   ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
   resultSet.next();
   Timestamp timestamp = resultSet.getTimestamp(1);
   ZonedDateTime timeInUTC = timestamp.toLocalDateTime().atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
   LocalDateTime timeInToronto = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(timeInUTC.toInstant(), ZoneId.of("America/Toronto"));
   ```