# How to parse a string into a java.sql.date

Tags: java, sql, date, jdbc, formatting

Hi i am trying to parse a string into a java.sql.date

Here is what i am doing

```
private static SimpleDateFormat sdfout = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm");
          try{
            String date = "2010.09.30.13.18";
        task.setDueDate(new java.sql.Date(sdfout.parse(date).getTime()));
    }
```

The problem is that i only get the date back.  Not the time.

Am i doing this correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code logic is fine, you only need [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) instead of [`java.sql.Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html). The SQL timestamp represents both the date and time parts, like date in Java. The SQL date represents only the date part.

#### See also:

- [Handling timestamps in MySQL using JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323618/handling-mysql-datetimes-and-timestamps-in-java/3323870#3323870)

---

Noted should be that you should prefer [`java.util.Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) over `java.sql.Timestamp` in the model objects and use the `Timestamp` only at the very moment when you're about to set it in a SQL query. This separates the model objects from the JDBC API and improves their portability and reusability.

Answer (score 0):

The `java.sql.Date` (according to JavaDoc)

> A thin wrapper around a millisecond
>   value that allows JDBC to identify
>   this as an SQL DATE value.

It returns to you a representation of a SQL *DATE*.

The `java.sql.Time` (according to JavaDoc)

> A thin wrapper around the
>   java.util.Date class that allows the
>   JDBC API to identify this as an SQL
>   TIME value.

It returns to you a representation of a SQL *TIME*.

If you want both date and time, use the `java.util.Date` instead of `java.sql.Date`.: