# Using a java.sql.Timestamp object in an sql query

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, timestamp

I am trying to run a query in java that uses a java.sql.Timestamp object as the date to compare with in the where clause.

Here is how the query string that is built in Java

```
 String getTransactionsSQL =  "Select transaction_seq " +
    "From transactions ct " +
    "Where id = 'ABCD'" + 
    "And ct.out_msg_timestamp" +
    "<= to_date('" + parseDate.getTimeStamp() +"','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS..')" +
    "order by transaction_seq";
```

The statement `parseDate.getTimeStamp()` returns a `java.sql.TimeStamp` object that contains a date. Here is an example output of `System.out.println(parseDate.getTimeStamp());`

```
2011-03-07 05:47:57.0
```

When i run the above query i get this error

```
 java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

Any clues?

Comment: What is the Oracle datatype of ct.out_msg_timestamp?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323618/handling-mysql-datetimes-and-timestamps-in-java

Comment: Brilliant thanks. I have changed it to use PreparedStatement and SetTimeStamp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use PreparedStatement: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Never use string concatenation to pass arguements to SQL commands (security risk: SQL injection)!

Comment: Here's the tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: I have to copy that! You should not use String concatenation in SQL like that

Comment: To be more precise, you should use `preparedStatement.setTimeStamp(index, timeStamp);`.

Comment: Thanks guys but is this not only a problem for web based applications? Is it also possible for daemon type applications?

Comment: @Ziggy: you should never use string literals for dates/timestamps. Always use a PreparedStatement, it's not only about SQL injenction but also about maintainability and robustness. When converting a date/timestamp to a string you are always influenced by locale settings (and maybe even different JDK versions)

Comment: @Ziggy, most importantly, it's about performance. When you hard-wire parameters to Oracle, Oracle will need to do a hard-parse of your SQL statement every time and re-calculate the query execution plan. A prepared statement is in fact a cursor shared by many database calls and sessions...