# MySQL datetime not returning time

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL db with a table containing a `datetime` column.

However, I cannot find a way in Java to return this as some sort of [`Time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html) object within Java.

I can call `resultset.getString("Date")` and it will return the `datetime`, but this is no good as there is no way to compare dates, etc., on the string.

I can also call `resultset.getDate("Date")`, but this doesn't return the time at all.

Comment: Did you try `getTime()` or  `getTimeStamp()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling MySQL datetimes and timestamps in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323618/handling-mysql-datetimes-and-timestamps-in-java)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the getTime() or getTimestamp() methods as suggested in the comment by Thomas. To give an example however...

Say for a table you query like this: `rs = stmt.executeQuery("select timeCol, dateCol, dateTimeCol from dateTimeTable");`

You could do:

```
java.sql.Time dbSqlTime = rs.getTime(1);
java.sql.Date dbSqlDate = rs.getDate(2);
java.sql.Timestamp dbSqlTimestamp = rs.getTimestamp(3);
```

If you want to use the Java date object:

```
java.util.Date dbSqlTimeConverted = new java.util.Date(dbSqlTime.getTime());
java.util.Date dbSqlDateConverted = new java.util.Date(dbSqlDate.getTime());
```

I would also check out [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) for working with Dates in Java, makes life much simpler.

Finally, its worth noting that there are a few differences between Timestamp and DateTime in MySQL. Namely that Timestamp has a timezone and the server will return a queried Timestamp in the Server's local time (which can be annoying). My advice is to use DateTime and always keep dates/times in the same timezone (i.e. UTC). See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

Comment: `java.sql.Timestamp` is a subclass of `java.util.Date`. You can just upcast instead of recreating it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, only getTimesStamp() will return the Date and time in one shot when querying Mysql :

Column: startTime: 
value: 2014-09-29 20:49:41

Java:

```
java.sql.Timestamp dbSqlTimestamp = rs.getTimestamp("startTime");
System.out.println("dbSqlTimestamp="+dbSqlTimestamp);
```

output:
    dbSqlTimestamp=2014-09-29 20:49:41.0