# query different in java that in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySql datetime not returning time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875196/mysql-datetime-not-returning-time)

If I do this from consele mysql:

```
SELECT CREATION from MYDATABASE WHERE NAME='MyData';
```

I get `2012-07-12 13:42:55`

but if do this from Java:

```
  String sql = "SELECT CREATION from MYDATABASE WHERE NAME=?";
  PreparedStatement ps = null;
  String creationQuery;
  ResultSet rs = null;
  try 
  {
      ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      ps.setString(1, "MyData");
      rs = ps.executeQuery();

      creationQuery = rs.next() ? rs.getString(1) : null;
  }
```

I get `2012-07-12 13:42:55.0`

Why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305973/java-util-date-vs-java-sql-date see the differenced between java and sql's date objects

Comment: Thank you so much and sorry for duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to do with the fact that what you receive from your Java query is a [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html), which is a wrapper to a regular `util.Date` that also holds nanoseconds.
If you look at the [`toString()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/sql/Timestamp.java#Timestamp.toString%28%29) method of that class you see that it is overridden to use the format

> yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fffffffff

where

> fffffffff

represent nanoseconds.

Both results represent the same time though, it is just a difference in representation.