# How can i search for the year in a date via a query?

Tags: java, sql

The records in the db look like this:

```
10//12/2013
10/13/2013
10/16/2013
10/20/2013
```

I want to search 2013 in the above records. Do i have to split first above values?

```
from CustomerRelations where DATE like'" + input + "'
```

Can I use `like` here?

Or how else can I do this?

```
   Query q = session.createQuery("from CustomerPayment where DATE like '" + code + "'");
```

The Above code does not work.

Comment: U stored them as datetime, not a string I might hope ?

Comment: i stored them as a varchar

Comment: If u want to search/calculate/do anything with dates as a date be sure to store them as a date or timestamp in your database. Will make your life much easier

[Getting values out of the DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875196/mysql-datetime-not-returning-time)
 and 
[between date1 and date2](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/between.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've saved the dates as VARCHAR do a wildcard String match

```
Query q = session.createQuery("from CustomerPayment where DATE like '%" + code + "'");
```

LIKE clause lets you use two wilcards:

- _ = matches just one single character
- % = matches any number of characters

Ideally, you should have created your table with a TIMESTAMP column. That would allow you to compare dates accurately and build queries like "fetch all customer payments in the last three months" etc.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
datepart(year,datefield)
```

where datefield is your field from which you want to retrieve the year

```
Query q = session.createQuery("SELECT date FROM CustomerPayment WHERE datepart(year,"+Convert.ToDateTime(datefield)+")="+ input+";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your query to

```
Query q = session.createQuery("SELECT date FROM CustomerPayment WHERE date LIKE '%"+input+"'"
```

since your date field is a string, you must do the lookup via a string compare