# how to get JDBC Date format?

Tags: database, jdbc

I've looked through page, and didn't find satisfying answer.

Is there a possibility to get a default data format from JDBC?

I'am writing a program, where user can choose different type of databases (like Oracle, MSSQL etc.) and insert data to it. I need JDBC to say me what is the default format of date.

Is there anybody who has met this case before?

Thank you in advance for answers.

Answer (score 4):

You *shouldn't* need a date format. You should use `PreparedStatement` and call `setDate` or `setTimestamp` to pass the data. There should be no need to convert it into a string format, as you shouldn't be representing the values (or *any* values) within the SQL.

Answer (score 3):

You should usually not care about the date format. If you do, then it means that you're treating dates as strings by storing them as `String` in Java side and as `VARCHAR` in DB side. This is wrong. They should in Java side be stored as `java.util.Date` and in DB side as `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` or maybe `DATE` (if you don't care about the time part).

The normal way to store a date (with time) is to use [`PreparedStatement#setTimestamp()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp%28int,%20java.sql.Timestamp%29):

```
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO person (birthdate) VALUES (?)");
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
// ...
```

And the normal way to retrieve it back is to use [`ResultSet#getTimestamp()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp%28java.lang.String%29):

```
Date date = resultSet.getTimestamp("birthdate");
// ...
```

This not only removes the need to worry about DB-specific default date string formats, but this also allows for more fine grained control over selecting dates using `>`, `<`, `BETWEEN`, etc in SQL side and more fine grained date formatting using [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) in Java side.

#### See also:

- [Handling MySQL datetimes and timestamps in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323618/handling-mysql-datetimes-and-timestamps-in-java)