# Default JDBC date format when reading date as a string from ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm looking at some code that basically does the following:

```
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
String myDateStr = rs.getString("MY_DATE"); //field is of type Date
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'.0'");
Date myDate = sdf.parse(myDateStr);
```

On some environments the last line works, and on others it throws an Unparseable date exception. It looks like on some systems the default date format is 2013-01-25 00:00:00.0, and on others 2013-01-25 00:00:00.
The JVM, OS and Oracle version are different between the environments (all use Oracle and run on a unix variant though).

Changing the code might be complex. I'm wondering if there is an environment variable or similar that can be set to make the date format returned from rs.getString() consistent?

Comment: read this [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229727/how-to-get-jdbc-date-format)

Comment: Just to clarify - why I say it could be complex to change is the above code is actually split between different classes in a framework that is driven by a large xml configuration file.
Switching to read it as a java.sql.Date would be great, but doing so might have some downstream consequences...

Comment: Why on earth would you use `getString()` for a `DATE` column. That is totally senseless. Use `getDate()` and everything is fine.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

Date myDate = rs.getDate("MY_DATE");
```

or this :

```
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
String myDateStr = rs.getString("MY_DATE"); 
Date myDate = valueOf(myDateStr);
```

More about date: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html
More about ResultSet : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using

```
String myDateStr = rs.getString("MY_DATE")
```

you should use

```
Timestamp timestamp = rs.getTimestamp("MY_DATE");
```

JDBC / Database will handle the date transformation for you.

Answer (score 2):

If the field is of type `Date`, then read it as a `java.sql.Date` and do whatever conversion you need after that.  Otherwise you're at the mercy of the database implementation.

Answer (score 0):

For the Oracle JDBC driver I am using, the format is hard-coded in the driver library, so should only differ across systems if different driver versions are in use.

See my attempt to get an answer to the same question here: [Where is the date format specified when reading a date as a string from JDBC ResultSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104197/where-is-the-date-format-specified-when-reading-a-date-as-a-string-from-jdbc-res/21174524#21174524).

(Apologies for asking a separate question, but as your question had been answered multiple times with the ever-helpful "just don't do that" response, I tried again...).