# Oracle JDBC - Date format difference

Tags: java, oracle, date, jdbc

I have a Date type column in one of our tables and when I query the database I get the date from the resultset like:

```
 final String createdDate = resultSet.getString("received_date");
```

If I run this on OC4J container on Java 5 I get

```
2014-12-26 05:57:31.0
```

while on Tomcat with Java 8 I get

```
2014-12-26 05:57:31
```

The JDBC driver are of different versions - do you think I should blame the driver for this? Is it a good direction regarding the investigation? Or is it more about Java version difference?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `getString` at all if it's a `Date` column? Why not fetch it *as a date*?

Comment: No, you should blame it on the poor decision for storing a Date type in a String column.  Formatting is a rendering issue.

Comment: It is a legacy code, do not ask why it was implemented so... Actually this is not the strangest  thing in that codebase...

Comment: Legacy code can still be corrected. At the very least you can specify the date format model explicitly with a `to_char()` call in your query, which you haven't shown; but retrieving it as a date would be better,

Comment: You are absolutely right, but I would like to understand why it behaves differently. How to fix it is a different topic

Comment: @HamoriZ - [looks like it is driver specific](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21174524/266304), but 'blame' is perhaps not the right term *8-)