# Mysql: java.sql.Time datatype using java and hibernate returns back java.sql.Date

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, datetime, jdbc

This seems to be very simple but somehow it is not working. I have to keep just the open time of a particular store in DB. I am using Time datatype of mysql for this. 
While storing i am doing:

java.sql.Time open = java.sql.Time.valueOf("09:00:00");

This works fine while storing the value in DB, but while fetching it, it return the value as 1970.01.01 09:00:00
I am using java and hibernate for the same.

I found this article
[java.sql.Time object being confused with java.sql.Date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569469/java-sql-time-object-being-confused-with-java-sql-date-object)

Is there just a simple way to achieve this..

Thanks
Vish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
java.util.Date getDepartureTime() { ... } // persistent property
```

According to the [JBoss documentation on annotations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/), this will solve your problem. java.sql.* is JDBC-specific. JPA/JDO/etc. use java.util.Date instead.