# How to retrieve mysql timestamp column from java.sql.timestamp

Tags: java, mysql

I have a timestamp column in a mysql table. I am unable to retrieve this value from java.sql.ResultSet using getTimestamp(String label).

```
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.getResultSet();
        rList = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (rs.next() != false){
            rList.add(rs.getString("urlstring"));
            if (rs.getTimestamp("mytimestamp") == null) {
                rList.add("null");
            } else {
                rList.add(rs.getTimestamp("mytimestamp").toString());
            }
        }
```

I can confirm that there are results in the resultset. When I omit the statements which attempt to retrieve the timestamp from the resultset, the list populates as expected, however, when I run the above code, there is no error but the list is empty.

Comment: rather than getting the value by name, maybe try by index.  Have you run this through a debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[getTimestamp()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp%28java.lang.String%29) works on DateTime MySQL columns.

See [Handling MySQL datetimes and timestamps in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323618/handling-mysql-datetimes-and-timestamps-in-java) in order to resolve your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you do

```
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.exequteQuery();
```

You could try (if this were the first `while (rs.next())`).

```
if (rs.first()) {
    do {
        rList.add(rs.getString("urlstring"));
        if (rs.getTimestamp("mytimestamp") == null) {
            rList.add("null");
        } else {
            rList.add(rs.getTimestamp("mytimestamp").toString());
        }
    } while (rs.next());
}
```