# Convert java.time.LocalDate into java.util.Date type

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I want to convert [`java.time.LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) into [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) type. Because I want to set the date into `JDateChooser`. Or is there any date chooser that supports [`java.time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) dates?

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242110/convert-java-util-date-to-java-time-localdate ?

Comment: **LGoodDatePicker** natively uses the java.time package (aka Java 8 time, or [JSR-310](http://www.threeten.org/). Specifically, LGoodDatePicker uses a "java.time.LocalDate" to store the date values. Screenshots and a demo are at the [Project Homepage](https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker).

Comment: More answers can be found on: [*LocalDate to java.util.Date and vice versa simplest conversion?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33066904/642706)

Answer (score 680, accepted):

```
Date date = Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

That assumes your date chooser uses the system default timezone to transform dates into strings.

Comment: I do not know why but using this conversion I get wrong results for dates before April 1893

Comment: Is it possible to avoid `atStartOfDay()`, since it changes the value of the date, as I understand it.

Comment: @yegor256 your comment doesn't make much sense to me. Why don't you ask your own question instead of commenting on a very old one?

Comment: @JBNizet your answer doesn't make much sense to me that's why I decided to clarify. Why don't you clarify it instead of making useless comments?

Comment: Because I don't see how and why it would need any clarification. 232 people upvoted this answer, thus finding it clear. You say atStartOfDay changes the value of the date. That doesn't make sense. atStartOfDay does what the javadoc says it does: it transforms a LocalDate into a LocalDateTime, on the same date, and at the start of the day.

Comment: @cornz Are you sure your results are incorrect?  If you're in Germany, then it might be something to do with the 6 minute 32 second glitch in the time in Germany, in April 1893.  See https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/germany/berlin?syear=1850 for some details.

Comment: This jsut works on android "O" and above. Iwant this method to get rid of LocalDate that can not support in my app, so this method is bring me same issue.

Answer (score 140):

Here's a utility class I use to convert the newer `java.time` classes to `java.util.Date` objects and vice versa:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateUtils {

  public static Date asDate(LocalDate localDate) {
    return Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
  }

  public static Date asDate(LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
    return Date.from(localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
  }

  public static LocalDate asLocalDate(Date date) {
    return Instant.ofEpochMilli(date.getTime()).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
  }

  public static LocalDateTime asLocalDateTime(Date date) {
    return Instant.ofEpochMilli(date.getTime()).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
  }
}
```

Edited based on @Oliv comment.

Comment: Isn't using `ZoneId.systemDefault()` problematic because timezones change over the corse of the year.  So if on 01-Jan I'm in timezone -05:00 (central), but then on 01-July I'm in the timezone -06:00 (central daylight) won't that cause inaccurate results because of daylight savings time?

Answer (score 112):

**Disclaimer:** For illustrating existing java apis only. Should not be used in production code.

You can use `java.sql.Date.valueOf()` method as:

```
Date date = java.sql.Date.valueOf(localDate);
```

No need to add time and time zone info here because they are taken implicitly.
See [LocalDate to java.util.Date and vice versa simplest conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33066904/simpliest-java8-localdate-to-java-util-date-conversion-and-vice-versa)

Comment: This was perfect for me, since what I needed was to pass LocalDate into SQL. However, if your Date formatter is going to do something about time zone shift before formatting the date, you might get one day too early depending on the local time zone, in which case you'll want one of the above options instead.

Comment: `java.sql.Date` is meant for the database layer, JDBC, JPA. The web layer (or any client application) should absolutely be free of any dependency from `java.sql.*`.

Comment: @Tiny java.sql.Date resides in rt.jar.
There are no any external dependencies. You just use language features.

Comment: `java.sql.Date` is just `java.util.Date` with its time set to `00:00:00` but the point in design perspective is that `java.sql.*` is not meant for a front layer which clients interact with like Servlets / JSP. [`java.util.Date` in Java side and `java.sql.Timestamp` or whatever applicable from `java.sql.*` in JDBC side](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3323870/1391249).

Comment: This is a "horrible hack" according with the java.time.* author: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33066904/localdate-to-java-util-date-and-vice-versa-simplest-conversion#comment72769769_33066935. In Java 9 `java.sql.*` classes will be a separate dependency.

Comment: Attention! This is NOT providing you with java.util.Date

Comment: If it is horrible hack why does not java include this simple stuff in java.util.. Day by day java is getting crazier than b4

Comment: I do actually like this hack, and e.g. baudelang is mentioning there as well, without any issues or comments, that it may be problematic (hack).
Check yourself: https://www.baeldung.com/java-date-to-localdate-and-localdatetime#localdate-date

Answer (score 20):

java.time has the Temporal interface which you can use to create Instant objects from most of the the time classes. Instant represents milliseconds on the timeline in the Epoch - the base reference for all other dates and times.

We need to convert the Date into a ZonedDateTime, with a Time and a Zone, to do the conversion:

```
LocalDate ldate = ...;
Instant instant = Instant.from(ldate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("GMT")));
Date date = Date.from(instant);
```

Answer (score 14):

In order to create a *java.util.Date* from a *java.time.LocalDate*, you have to

- add a time to the *LocalDate*
- interpret the date and time within a time zone
- get the number of seconds / milliseconds since *epoch*
- create a *java.util.Date*

The code might look as follows:

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
Date date = new Date(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")).toEpochSecond() * 1000);
```

Comment: Typo in zone id (ZoneIf)

Comment: localDate.atStartOfDay() creates a ZonedDateTime, but there is no toEpochSecond() method for ZonedDateTime.

Comment: @KevinSadler: The method `toEpochSecond` is inherited from `java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#toEpochSecond--

Comment: @nosid Thank you for your correction. When I use code completion in Eclipse it (and toInstance) isn't present as an option. But if I type it in full it seems to be accepted. I had wrongly concluded it wasn't a method because of this fact and that I didn't see it on the Javadoc for ZonedDateTime, as it is listed as an inherited method, as you say. Sorry, please accept an upclick :)

Answer (score 14):

This works for me:

```
java.util.Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(localDate.toString());
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toString--

Comment: this is quite inefficient

Comment: Converting to Instant might be verbose, but building and parsing a String is like going from New York to Mexico City via Tokyo...

Comment: @ehecatl Beware... in the future NY -> Tokyo -> Mexico City may be done within hour(s) ;)

Comment: this works better for my use cases when I no longer have the timezone info at the time of conversion. E.g. work with Freemaker to print the date.

Comment: this is wrong solution because SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe

Comment: @OlegUshakov if it's inlined like this, then thread-safety will not fail

Answer (score 12):

**Kotlin Solution:**

1) Paste this extension function somewhere.

```
fun LocalDate.toDate(): Date = Date.from(this.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant())
```

2) Use it, and never google this again.

```
val myDate = myLocalDate.toDate()
```

Comment: How is "switch to Kotlin" simple? This is a Java question.

Comment: Converting the Java LocalDate to Date is a common, annoying problem for any JVM developer. This is a solution for Kotlin developers.

Comment: Thanks! i was seeking for Kotlin solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static Date convertToTimeZone(Date date, String tzFrom, String tzTo) {
    return Date.from(LocalDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.of(tzTo)).atZone(ZoneId.of(tzFrom)).toInstant());
}
```

Comment: Please explain your solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
    try {
        Date utilDate= formatter.parse(date.toString());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // handle exception
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```java
public Date convertFrom(LocalDate date) {
    return Date.valueOf(date);
}
```

Comment: The valueOf method is a member of java.sql.Date, and the question specifies java.util.Date.

Answer (score -3):

Simple

```
public Date convertFrom(LocalDate date) {
    return java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(date.atStartOfDay());
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
localDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding additional information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: The question is how to convert from LocalDate to Date, not to String.

Answer (score -6):

```
java.util.Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

Comment: how your answer is different from accepted one after 4 years? Copy-paste to achieve reputation increase?