# How to extract epoch from LocalDate and LocalDateTime?

Tags: java, time, java-8, epoch, java-time

How do I extract the epoch value to `Long` from instances of `LocalDateTime` or `LocalDate`? I've tried 
the following, but it gives me other results:

```
LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.parse("04.02.2014  19:51:01", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy  HH:mm:ss"));
System.out.println(time.getLong(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_DAY)); // gives 71461
System.out.println(time.getLong(ChronoField.EPOCH_DAY)); // gives 16105
```

What I want is simply the value `1391539861` for the local datetime `"04.02.2014  19:51:01"`.
My timezone is `Europe/Oslo` UTC+1 with daylight saving time.

Comment: Please explain your expected number 1396468261. I get without timezone correction: 1391543461 (see edit in my answer). 57 days difference!

Comment: @MenoHochschild I've updated my question with timezone info and corrected the actual value from GTM to localtime. Is there an easier way to get the epoch of some `LocalDateTime` other than manually calculating it?

Comment: Coming back from my pause, see my update.

Answer (score 213, accepted):

The classes `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime` do not contain information about the *timezone* or *time offset*, and seconds since epoch would be ambigious without this information. However, the objects have several methods to convert them into date/time objects with timezones by passing a `ZoneId` instance.

**LocalDate**

```
LocalDate date = ...;
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault(); // or: ZoneId.of("Europe/Oslo");
long epoch = date.atStartOfDay(zoneId).toEpochSecond();
```

**LocalDateTime**

```
LocalDateTime time = ...;
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault(); // or: ZoneId.of("Europe/Oslo");
long epoch = time.atZone(zoneId).toEpochSecond();
```

Comment: Is it possible to avoid using ZoneId, or use with a customized, constant ZoneId instance (of +0 , meaning GMT) ? I ask this because I want all calculations be normalized to it. Also, how do I do the opposite: convert from epoch time to LocalDate/LocalDateTime (also without ZoneId, or with the GMT one) ?

Comment: Never mind. Found it: `ZoneId.ofOffset("UTC", ZoneOffset.ofHours(0))`

Comment: A simpler approach is just `long epoch = time.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC)` for UTC cases, or where you already know the timezone, or `long epoch = time.toEpochSecond(ZoneId.systemDefault());` if you want to go that route.

Comment: This might sound ridiculous but how about converting back from epoch to LocalDate, LocalTime & LocalDateTime

Comment: Never mind I think I found it;     `Instant.ofEpochMilli(responseTime).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalTime()`

Comment: I just want to note that `ZonedDateTime` also exists and is much more useful in my experience since it can parse the `Z` (or other time zones) at the end of strings into the correct time zone

Comment: Do not use ZoneId.systemDefault ... be explicit about what you want, especially since the timezone is gone in the LocalDateTime.

Answer (score 40):

'Millis since unix epoch' represents an instant, so you should use the Instant class:

```
private long toEpochMilli(LocalDateTime localDateTime)
{
  return localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
    .toInstant().toEpochMilli();
}
```

Comment: it is incorrect to use `ZoneId.systemDefault()` because unix epoch refers to UTC

Comment: @ACV Are you still agree what you once thought? Did the API designer failed to define `ZonedDateTime#toInstant`?

Comment: @JinKwon I was merely refering to the fact that `ZoneId.systemDefault()` may not necessarily return the timezon the OP was expecting: `My timezone is Europe/Oslo`. So they should use `ZoneId.of("Europe/Oslo")` instead as suggested in other answers. As for `ZonedDateTime.toInstant()` - its javadoc clearly explains the implementation: `This returns an Instant representing the same point on the time-line as this date-time. The calculation combines the local date-time and offset.`

Comment: `ZoneId.systemDefault()` seems to return UTC, so systemDefault should be fine

Answer (score 14):

The conversion you need requires the offset from UTC/Greewich, or a time-zone.

If you have an offset, there is a [dedicated method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoLocalDateTime.html#toEpochSecond-java.time.ZoneOffset-) on `LocalDateTime` for this task:

```
long epochSec = localDateTime.toEpochSecond(zoneOffset);
```

If you only have a `ZoneId` then you can obtain the `ZoneOffset` from the `ZoneId`:

```
ZoneOffset zoneOffset = ZoneId.of("Europe/Oslo").getRules().getOffset(ldt);
```

But you may find conversion via `ZonedDateTime` simpler:

```
long epochSec = ldt.atZone(zoneId).toEpochSecond();
```

Comment: If you only care about UTC, there is `long epochSec = localDateTime.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC);`

Answer (score 2):

This is one way without using a time zone:

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
long epoch = (now.getLong(ChronoField.EPOCH_DAY) * 86400000) + now.getLong(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_DAY);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#isSupported-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-) to see which fields are supported. You will find for `LocalDateTime`:

```
•NANO_OF_SECOND 
•NANO_OF_DAY 
•MICRO_OF_SECOND 
•MICRO_OF_DAY 
•MILLI_OF_SECOND 
•MILLI_OF_DAY 
•SECOND_OF_MINUTE 
•SECOND_OF_DAY 
•MINUTE_OF_HOUR 
•MINUTE_OF_DAY 
•HOUR_OF_AMPM 
•CLOCK_HOUR_OF_AMPM 
•HOUR_OF_DAY 
•CLOCK_HOUR_OF_DAY 
•AMPM_OF_DAY 
•DAY_OF_WEEK 
•ALIGNED_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH 
•ALIGNED_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_YEAR 
•DAY_OF_MONTH 
•DAY_OF_YEAR 
•EPOCH_DAY 
•ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH 
•ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_YEAR 
•MONTH_OF_YEAR 
•PROLEPTIC_MONTH 
•YEAR_OF_ERA 
•YEAR 
•ERA
```

The field INSTANT_SECONDS is - of course - not supported because a `LocalDateTime` cannot refer to any absolute (global) timestamp. But what is helpful is the field [EPOCH_DAY](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#EPOCH_DAY) which counts the elapsed days since 1970-01-01. Similar thoughts are valid for the type `LocalDate` (with even less supported fields).

If you intend to get the non-existing millis-since-unix-epoch field you also need the timezone for converting from a local to a global type. This conversion can be done much simpler, see other [SO-posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22929237/convert-java-time-localdate-into-java-util-date-type).

**Coming back to your question and the numbers in your code:**

```
The result 1605 is correct
  => (2014 - 1970) * 365 + 11 (leap days) + 31 (in january 2014) + 3 (in february 2014)
The result 71461 is also correct => 19 * 3600 + 51 * 60 + 1
```

16105L * 86400 + 71461 = 1391543461 seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00 (attention, no timezone)
Then you can subtract the timezone offset (watch out for possible multiplication by 1000 if in milliseconds).

**UPDATE after given timezone info:**

```
local time = 1391543461 secs
offset = 3600 secs (Europe/Oslo, winter time in february)
utc = 1391543461 - 3600 = 1391539861
```

As JSR-310-code with two equivalent approaches:

```
long secondsSinceUnixEpoch1 =
  LocalDateTime.of(2014, 2, 4, 19, 51, 1).atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Oslo")).toEpochSecond();

long secondsSinceUnixEpoch2 =
  LocalDate
    .of(2014, 2, 4)
    .atTime(19, 51, 1)
    .atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Oslo"))
    .toEpochSecond();
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Got the right result by using `LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.parse("04.02.2014  19:51:01", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy  HH:mm:ss"));` and then `Long epoch = time.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Oslo")).toEpochSecond();`.

Answer (score 1):

Extracting [two good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990067/how-to-extract-epoch-from-localdate-and-localdatetime#comment97198888_22992578) found in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990067/how-to-extract-epoch-from-localdate-and-localdatetime#comment84263933_23015661) on this post,

> If you only care about UTC (Coordinated Universal Time), there is

```
final long epoch = localDateTime.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

> or where you already know the timezone

```
final long epoch = localDateTime.toEpochSecond(ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

More information from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoLocalDateTime.html#toEpochSecond-java.time.ZoneOffset-

> **toEpochSecond**
>
> ```
> default long toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset offset)
> ```
>
> Converts this date-time to the number of seconds from the epoch of
> 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.
>
> This combines this local date-time and the specified offset to
> calculate the epoch-second value, which is the number of elapsed
> seconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. Instants on the time-line after the
> epoch are positive, earlier are negative.
>
> This default implementation calculates from the epoch-day of the date
> and the second-of-day of the time.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> offset - the offset to use for the conversion, not null
>
> **Returns:**
>
> the number of seconds from the epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z

Answer (score 0):

Convert from ***human readable date to epoch***:

```
long epoch = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyyHH:mm:ss").parse("01/01/1970 01:00:00").getTime() / 1000;
```

Convert from ***epoch to human readable date***:

```
String date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyyHH:mm:ss").format(new java.util.Date (epoch*1000));
```

For other language converter:
https://www.epochconverter.com

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.