# Convert Joda LocalDateTime to Unix timestamp

Tags: java, jodatime, unix-timestamp

How do I convert a `org.joda.time.LocalDateTime` to an Unix timestamp, given that local time is in UTC timezone?

Example:

`new LocalDateTime(2015, 10, 02, 11, 31, 40)` > `1443785500`.

Comment: If I recall, Unix timestamp is the number of seconds since the Unix epoch, maybe something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990067/how-to-extract-epoch-from-localdate-and-localdatetime)

Comment: A `LocalDateTime` doesn't have a time zone, so it doesn't represent one ponit in time. You need to specify a time zone in order for that to make any sense.

Comment: @MadProgrammer That's link is about Java 8 time api, not Joda! Unfortunatelly I haven't found the same thread for Joda l.d.t.

Comment: @DenisKulagin Opps, was a quick search :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer N.P., I've also encountered those question and even tried to put it in code. No luck, obviously)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Given that you want the Unix timestamp "the given `LocalDateTime`, in UTC" the simplest approach is just to convert it to a `DateTime` by specifying the `DateTimeZone` for UTC, and convert that:

```
LocalDateTime local = new LocalDateTime(2015, 10, 02, 11, 31, 40);
DateTime utc = local.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
long secondsSinceEpoch = utc.getMillis() / 1000;
```

Note the use of seconds here as a Unix timestamp - other APIs (e.g. `java.util.Date`) may expect milliseconds since the Unix epoch.

Comment: Also you can use `DateTimeConstants.MILLIS_PER_SECOND` instead of `1000` or use `Duration.millis(local.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC).getMillis).getStandardSeconds`.

Comment: Simple and neat, When the Joda developer is making out reasons to expose getLocalMillis() as public. Link: https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/issues/87