# get tomorrow date 1:00pm in UNIX timestrap

Tags: java

Can't find any solution how to get tomorrow's date 13:00.
For example: today is 16.01.2019, I need to find how in unix timestrap is 17.01.2019 13:00.

tried this:

```
LocalDateTime tomorrowWithTime = 
LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1), 13:00);
```

to set manually 13:00, add it to tomorrows date and then convert to unix timestrap, but no luck :(

Comment: What is the actual output?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What exactly do you mean by "but no luck"? You have two operations you need to perform: 1) Obtain the appropriate LocalDateTime (or ZonedDateTime, which I'd suggest might be a better fit); 2) Convert a `LocalDateTime` (or `ZonedDateTime`) to a Unix timestamp. Those are very separate - if you've managed the first part, then it would be worth making this question *just* about the second part, ideally showing what you've tried and what happened.

Comment: no output. It's not allowed to add time like this and code doesnt work. I've tried different types to write time like: 13, 00, 00 or 13-00-00. Dunno how to set time manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close to it. To get the `LocalDateTime` it's

```
LocalDateTime tomorrowWithTime = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1), LocalTime.of(13, 0));
```

Then to convert it to unix timestamp please have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990067/how-to-extract-epoch-from-localdate-and-localdatetime). In summary you have to give a `ZoneId`: (to give a working answer I'll use your system zoneId):

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault(); //Or the appropriate zone
long timestamp = tomorrowWithTime.atZone(zoneId).toEpochSecond();
```

---

By the way, if your issue was that you didn't know what to give as parameters to  `LocalDateTime.of()`, your first reflex should be to have a look at [the API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#of-java.time.LocalDate-java.time.LocalTime-) to see what parameters it accepts.

Comment: thank you VERY much. it's exactly what I need. BTW, from what library is "time.atZone(zoneId).toEpochSecond()"? My IntelliJ doesn't know :)

Comment: Sorry, it was supposed to be `tomorrowWithTime.atZone()...`, I edited it. It comes from [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-)

Comment: Thank you :) the code now works  `LocalDateTime tomorrowWithTime = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1), LocalTime.of(13, 0));

        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();
        long epochSec = tomorrowWithTime.atZone(zoneId).toEpochSecond();`