# java.time.LocalDate to java.util.Date

Tags: java, java.util.date

What is the best way to convert from  `java.time.LocalDate` to `java.util.Date` ?

```
Date.from(dateToReturn.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()
```

I have been trying this one but does not seem to work correct with the time although converts the date month and year correctly.

Update : java.time.LocalDate does not save time informations Just used java.time.LocalDateTime instead and everything works fine.

Comment: Helpful link http://blog.progs.be/542/date-to-java-time

Comment: What time do you expect? A LocalDate does not have any time information associated.

Comment: Maybe `myDate.setDate(myLocalDate.toEpochDay())`?

Comment: You say it “does not seem to work correct with the time.”  Please describe the result you got, and the result you were expecting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Java.time LocalDate into java.util Date type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22929237/convert-java-time-localdate-into-java-util-date-type)

Comment: @BasilBourque: OP's original question states (indirectly) that that answer does not work for him.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
LocalDate ld = ...;
Instant instant = ld.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
Date res = Date.from(instant);
```

Check out this blog post, [Converting between Date and java8 java.time.LocalDateTime, LocalDate and LocalTime](http://blog.progs.be/542/date-to-java-time) by joachim.

Comment: The link gave me the answer ! My (Stupid) mistake was that I assummed that java.time.LocalDate is the equivalent of java util Date while I need to use java.time.LocalDateTime  cause  LocalDate does not save time informations ! Thanks anyway !