# Can Java's sql.Date produce an off by one error?

Tags: java, sql-server, date

I have a `Date` object that is using the method `getTime` to return the milliseconds since 1/1/1970.

```
invoiceDate.getTime();
```

These milliseconds are passed to a `java.sql.Date` constructor like so:

```
new java.sql.Date( invoiceDate.getTime() );
```

And the result is a date in *yyyy-MM-dd* format.

Now my question is this, is it possible that `java.sql.Date` can produce an off by one error? For example, say the *invoiceDate* is set to *Thu Jul 02 00:00:00 CDT 2015*, is it then possible that java.sql.Date produces *2015-07-01*?

Comment: Do you have some code that is producing an off by 1 error? Why do you suspect this may be possible?

Comment: No code that i can see is causing this. QA at the place i work claims that this happened, however, I cannot reproduce the supposed off by one error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Java date does not store timezone so your invoiceDate and the new date object are equal. It prints CDT in toString() because that is the timezone of your jvm

Also see the docs for [Date.getTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime())

> Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT
>   represented by this Date object.

And the for [Date(long)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(long))

> Allocates a Date object and initializes it to represent the specified
>   number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the
>   epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

Answer (score 0):

No. However the it doesn't care about time zones, which can create some problems. Also be aware that months count from zero while days are from 1.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted Answer by 6ton is correct. The `toString` methods on java.util.Date and java.sql.Date silently apply your JVM’s current default time zone to the date-time value which is in UTC zone<sup>†</sup>.

## java.time

This is one of *many* reasons to avoid using the old java.util.Date/.Calendar and java.sql.Date. Try to do the bulk of your work using the new java.time framework in Java 8 and later, or the 3rd-party [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.

If you truly only care about date without time-of-day, meaning your app will never leave one locality (time zone), then use a date-only class. The old date-time classes lack this. Both java.time and Joda-Time offer such a date-only class, both called `LocalDate`.

Using `LocalDate` this way has been discussed many times on StackOverflow. Please search for more info.

- [Convert Java.time LocalDate into java.util Date type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22929237/642706)
- [Convert java.util.Date to java.time.LocalDate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21242110/642706)
- [java.time.LocalDate to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27250666/642706)

---

<sup>†</sup> There actually is a time zone assigned deep in the java.util.Date source code, but it is ignored for most purposes. Confusing? Yes. Yet *another* reason to avoid these old classes.