# Hibernate 4 with java.time.LocalDate and DATE() construct expects java.util.Date

Tags: java, hibernate, date, persistence

I'm trying to use `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime` with Java 8 in my app. I'm using Hibernate 4.3.5 and Spring. I followed this interesting tutorial here and all works but I've a problem when I use `DATE()` construct.

When I try to do:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE DATE(data)=DATE(:data)
```

I get an `IllegalArgumentException` because setParameter is expecting `java.util.Date` instead of `java.time.LocalDate`, if I don't use DATE() construction it is expecting `java.time.LocalDateTime`, I already implemented hibernate converters but I can't find a good solution for it (converting from `LocalDate` to `java.util.Date` doesn't look for me good), anyone knows how fix this problem?

Comment: Date date = Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()); (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22929237/convert-java-time-localdate-into-java-util-date-type). First match of google search

Comment: converting from LocalDate to java.util.Date doesn't look for me good, I already wrote it in my question, I'm interested why I can't use LocalDate in  this place.

Comment: "doesn't look for me good" can mean a lot of things. Did you mean it is not good? If so, why?

Comment: Because hibernate know that I want use LocalDateTime when I use full date with time, but it still trying use java.util.date when I just want compare dates.