# Codec not found for requested operation: [date <-> java.util.Date]

Tags: java, cassandra

In Cassandra a column type is set to Date and in Model class type of field is set to java.util.Date with getters and setters. During `com.datastax.driver.mapping.Mapper.save` I get the following exception:

```
Codec not found for requested operation: [date <-> java.util.Date]

Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [date <-> java.util.Date]
at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException.copy(CodecNotFoundException.java:56)
at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException.copy(CodecNotFoundException.java:25)
at com.datastax.driver.mapping.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:41)
at com.datastax.driver.mapping.Mapper.save(Mapper.java:272)
```

Found the following during Google search:

```
DATE      <-> com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate : use getDate()
```

Comment: Convert java.util.Date to LocalDate

Comment: Cassandra Date field maps Java LocalDate, you need to convert 
Check this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/27323328/2320144

Comment: to convert from Date to LocalDate, I'd need to change data type of filed in Model class to use its setter, right?

Comment: Yes, You need to Change your data type to LocalDate

Comment: Actually, changing Date to LocalDate causes another issue. `Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class java.time.LocalDate] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method (through reference chain: com.test.model.User["testList"]->com.test.model.DepTest["testDob"])`

Answer (score 7):

You must convert java.util.Date to [com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.2/com/datastax/driver/core/LocalDate.html)

Example:

```
 LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.fromMillisSinceEpoch(date.getTime());
```

Comment: I was using the POJO mapper and I defined the `date` field as `com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate` and it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue with using timestamp

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.type.codec.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [TIMESTAMP <-> java.util.Date]
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.type.codec.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [TIMESTAMP <-> java.util.Date]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.CachingCodecRegistry.createCodec(CachingCodecRegistry.java:609) ~[java-driver-core-4.9.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.DefaultCodecRegistry$1.load(DefaultCodecRegistry.java:95) ~[java-driver-core-4.9.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.DefaultCodecRegistry$1.load(DefaultCodecRegistry.java:92) ~[java-driver-core-4.9.0.jar:na]
```

Starting with driver 4.0, the CQL type timestamp is not mapped to `java.util.Date` anymore, but to `java.time.Instant`.
Using Instant worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Replace Date type with LocalDate type in your Entity class:-

```
private LocalDate createdDate;
```