# Java 8 DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, java-8, datetimeformatter

I need to replace SimpleDataFormat with Java 8 DateTimeFormatter. Below is the code with SimpleDateFormat.

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = sdf.parse(source);
```

Now I need to change it to DateTimeFormatter. I tried as below

```
LocalDateTime ld = LocalDateTime.now();
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date startdate = dtf.parse(dtf);
```

Now this is generating exception.

Comment: Edit your post to include what you have tried and why that doesn't work

Comment: @Janar I have updated the question. can you please upvote it now

Comment: What is the exception, cant you just handle it with a `try catch` clause?

Comment: Also, your pattern isn't in quotes

Comment: `dtf.parse(dtf)` won't throw an exception - it won't compile.

Comment: @Janar that is typo... can you tell me the solution what needs to be replaced with dtf.parse(dtf)

Comment: What does `ld` have to do with it? And have you read the documentation for `DateTimeFormatter`? It has an example...

Comment: @JonSkeet correct I need it in Date object

Comment: So what makes you think you need to use `DateTimeFormatter` at all? I'd urge you to avoid using `java.util.Date` entirely.

Comment: I think you want to use `LocalDate` rather than `LocalDateTime`.

Answer (score 4):

```
   DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
   LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse("2017-02-11", dtf);
   System.out.println(localDate.toString());
```

if you want Date object from LocalDate,the following works

```
Date date = Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

As @JonSkeet advised, If you're using Java 8 you should probably avoid **java.util.Date** altogether

Answer (score 3):

If looking for equivalent of your sdf in DateTimeFormatter try `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE`
Explore the `DateTimeFormatter` class for more formats.

```
 LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.now();
    time.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
```

Use `LocalDate` instead of `LocalDateTime` if intrested in Date only.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
java.util.Date.from(

LocalDate.parse( "2017-01-23" )
         .atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
         .toInstant()

)
```

## No need of formatting pattern

No formatting pattern needed. Your input string happens to be in standard ISO 8601 format. These standard formats are used by default in the java.time classes for parsing and generating strings.

## `LocalDate`

Use `LocalDate` for a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2017-01-23" );
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

If you want a date-time, let java.time determine the first moment of the day. Do not assume that first moment is `00:00:00`.

Determining first moment of the day requires a time zone. The date varies around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z );
```

If you want to perceive that moment through the lens of UTC, extract an `Instant` object.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
```

The `Instant` is equivalent to the old legacy class `java.util.Date`. Both represent a moment on the timeline in UTC. The modern class has a finer resolution, nanoseconds rather than milliseconds.

## Avoid `java.util.Date`

As others mentioned, you should stick with the modern java.time classes. But if you must, you can convert. Look to new methods added to the old classes.

```
java.util.Date d = java.util.Date.from( instant ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it would be -

```
    LocalDateTime ld = LocalDateTime.now();
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String date = ld.format(dtf);
```

Comment: I need it in Date object

Comment: @user1111880: Then you shouldn't be using `DateTimeFormatter`, which is designed for the `java.time` classes.

Comment: @user1111880 here is the perfect example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22929237/convert-java-time-localdate-into-java-util-date-type