# How to convert "2019-04-24" to "24-Apr-2019" date format?

Tags: java, date

I am trying to convert "2019-04-24" to "24-Apr-2019" this but it is converting it as "24-Jan-19".

This is the code I am using:

```
public static String dateFormatConvert(String date, String srcDateFormat, String targetDataFormat) throws ParseException {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(srcDateFormat);
    Date srcDate = dateFormat.parse(date);
    DateFormat destDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(targetDataFormat);
    return destDateFormat.format(srcDate);
}
```

Calling it:

```
    String date1 = CommonUtil.dateFormatConvert("2019-04-24", "yyyy-MM-DD", "DD-MMM-YY"); -> This is one of the format used (DD-MMM-YY) out of many
    System.out.println(date1);
```

What's going wrong here?

Comment: Hint: did you read the `SimpleDateFormat` documentation *very carefully* when coming up with your format strings? What does `DD` mean, according to that documentation, and what did you expect it to mean?

Comment: Step 1: Use `java.time` instead.

Comment: Use LocalDate.of to set specific date then use DateTimeFormatter.ofpattern to specify the pattern u like dd MMM yyyy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42175899/java-8-datetimeformatter

Comment: Besides `DD` instead of `dd`, use of `YY` instead of `yy` or `yyyy` is also wrong.

Comment: `java.time.LocalDate.parse( "2019-04-24" ).format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uuuu" ).withLocale( Locale.US ) )` See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/XwW8qC). Use only *java.time* classes. Never use `Date`/`Calendar`.

Comment: I too recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Also don’t keep your dates in strings and don’t convert them from one sting format to another. Keep your dates in `LocalDate` objects and only format them into strings when you need a string, like for presentation to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

D - Day in year

d - Day in month

The correct code would be:

```
date1 = dateFormatConvert("2019-04-24", "yyyy-MM-dd", "dd-MMM-yyyy");
```