# Timer with Date and Times Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

My question is simple: Is it possible to use date and times of Java 8 with the class Timer (java.util.Timer).

```
 Timer timer = new Timer(); 
 timer.schedule(TimerTask task, Date time)
```

In that case this class use Date, is there any solution for LocalTime, LocalDate, LocalDateTime.

Comment: You should avoid Timer, and use a ScheduledExecutorService in the first place. But anyway, Date has a method from(Instant).

Comment: Hmmm why should I avoid Timer? Thanks

Comment: For several reasons detailed in *Java concurrency in practice*: single thread which can reduce accuracy, bad handling of runtime exceptions, lack of control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java8 release is not affecting the java.util.Date class, that would be a terrible compatibility issue for the old implementations running over there,

java8 instead is bringing new APIs for time manipulation

so 
can we do this in java 8?

```
Timer timer = new Timer(); 
timer.schedule(task, time);
```

yes, as soon as time is a java.util.Date

can we schedule a Timer in java 8 with the new time api features like 
**LocalDate** and **LocalTime**?

No, not directly, but those classes have [methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) allowing you to soon or later construct your old date object e.g.

```
java.util.Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(localDate.toString());
```

as [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22929420/982161)

Comment: As mentioned in a comment in the question, the Date class has the method from that can be used to create a Date from an Instant. So this is better than using SimpleDateFormat to parse a string.

Answer (score 1):

No, It is not possible. Even more it is not recommended to use it (you can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/409993/2065796)). Alternatively you can use `ScheduledExecutorService`, here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20388073/2065796).