# Save java.time.LocalDate in Date column of DB2 database

Tags: java, date, db2, localdate

How to persist an item of `java.time.LocalDate` in a column of type `Date` within a DB2 database ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What didn't work?

Comment: Actually now to unblock the situation I changer my attribute to String but not for too much time because this will not help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a [JDBC driver](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) supporting [JDBC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) 4.2 or later, use:

- `PreparedStatement::setObject()`
- `ResultSet::getObject()`

Example:

```
myPStmt.setObject( … , myLocalDate ) ;
```

Retrieving that date.

```
LocalDate myLocalDate = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

Comment: Can I ask you a question? Where do you get a DB2 driver that implements JDBC 4.2? I could only find 4.0/4.1 implementations at https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/382667. Also Maven Central has similar drivers, but 4.2 drivers are nowhere to be found.

Comment: @TheImpaler I don't know about DB2. I only use Postgres & H2. I imagine IBM *must* be providing such drivers. JDBC 4.2 came out several years ago, and we are already onto JDBC 4.3. See [JSR 221](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221). Also, you may consider 3rd party drivers as well, possibly open-source or commercial.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a FAQ. Convert the java.time.LocalDate to java.util.Date which you can persist to a DB2 DATE column.

Related thread with example: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22929237/convert-java-time-localdate-into-java-util-date-type)

You can also convert to java.sql.Date

Comment: How is is answering the question?

Comment: If that answered the question, then this should be marked as duplicate.  Except the OP doesn't want a different Java type, they want the _database_ type, which is rather different (and requires library support).