# Java parse date string returns wrong month

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat, date-parsing

I try to parse a date string, but get wrong month, why?

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD", Locale.US).parse("2018-03-08")
```

**Why this returns month as Jan?**

Please check screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Use `dd` not `DD` . The former is for day in month, the latter for day in year .

Comment: try new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US).parse("2018-03-08");

Comment: Also note that calling `setLenient(false)` on your `SimpleDateFormat` before using it, would prevent some attempts to interpret a wrong `String`. In your case attempting to parse the `String` would give a `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2018-03-08"` .

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with. It will also alleviate your problem: the modern `LocalDate` class parses your `2018-03-08` without any explicit formatter because it is in its default format (ISO 8601). So no way to get the format pattern string wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the format you used as `"yyyy-MM-DD"`. The parser will parse in the sequence way:

- Your input value is `"2018-03-08"`
- `yyyy` -  will bring to the year 2018
- `MM` - will bring to the month MARCH

But what is `DD`? It's the number of the days from the beginning of the year.
So here it moved back to 8<sup>th</sup> day on this year (2018) which means January 8<sup>th</sup>.

That's why you are seeing January instead of March.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the [`java.time` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/)?

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse("2018-03-08");
```

If you want to convert the `LocalDate` to a `java.util.Date`, you can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22929420).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `dd` instead of `DD`

Try this :-

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US).parse("2018-03-08");
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this [tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-string-to-date-java/) if you are trying to display the month name you should use 3 M’s and isn’t the standard for the day to be `d` and not `D`

I would suggest trying `yyyy-MMM-dd`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this below and it is working fine by changing the `DD` to `dd`

```
try {
            Date date=  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.US).parse("2018-03-08");

            Calendar calendar= Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(date);
            Log.d("MONTH ","" + calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));



        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```