# How to get epoch milis from a date (LocalDate)

Tags: android, kotlin, epoch, localdate

I have a month July 2022 for example, I want get epoch milis for the first day of the month

1st July 2022 at midnight.

from the month I was able to get the 1st July 2022, but how to convert it into epoch milis for 1st July 22 midnight

```
    val datey = "July/2020"
    val dateFormaty = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM/yyyy")
    val yearMonthy = YearMonth.parse(datey, dateFormaty)
    val parsedDatey = yearMonthy.atDay(1)
```

I get 2022-07-01 for parsedDate, I want to get the date time for this date in epoch milis

Thanks
R

Comment: Have you [read the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toEpochDay--) ? Perhaps `parsedDatey.toEpochDay()` is the thing you're looking for? Watch out for this part of the documentation **This class does not store or represent a time or time-zone. Instead, it is a description of the date, as used for birthdays. It cannot represent an instant on the time-line without additional information such as an offset or time-zone.**

Comment: I tried that but it gave me a 1970 date, so that did not work for me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert java.time.LocalDate into java.util.Date type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22929237/convert-java-time-localdate-into-java-util-date-type)

Comment: "how to convert it into epoch milis for 1st July 22 midnight" your example literally never mentions nor provides the midnight part to the Date.

Answer (score 0):

Like I mentioned, LocalDate does not actually store any time information whatsoever, so transforming it to epoch isn't possible. Technically. Yet it is with some possible inacuracies.

How about something like this:

make the following extension function

```
fun LocalDate.toDate(): Date = Date.from(this.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant())
```

Note that it uses the system default timezone for this, to provide the necessary information.

then just use it.

```
val myDate = myLocalDate.toDate()
```

which would in your case, be `parsedDatey.toDate()`

But, we don't really even need the `Date` here. Lets avoid casting the `LocalDate` to `Date` then getting the epoch milli from there, and just do it from the provided `Instant` instead.

So the real answer to your question is this:

```
fun LocalDate.getEpochMillis(): long = this.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli()

// call this in your parsing method you posted
parsedDatey.getEpochMillis()
```