# Webpage displays the date without the time

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-mvc, jstl

We have following code on the jsp page

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${object.mydate}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" var="mydate" />
<c:out value="${mydate}"/>
```

My entity

```
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    @Column(name = "DATEEXAMPLE", length = 7)
    public Date getDateExample() {
        return this.dateexample;
    }
```

in Oracle Database field DATAEXAMPLE is DATA_TYPE "DATE" (and example entry, 14/08/21 17:01:20)

**Unfortunately, website displays me "2014-08-21 00:00:00"**

Somone know why?

I'am using Oracle Database 11g, Spring 3.2, Hibernate 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
```

As per the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/TemporalType.html), this maps to `java.sql.Date`. And guess what, it holds only the "date" part of the timestamp, not the "time" part. You need the other one, mapping to `java.sql.Timestamp`.

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
```

#### See also:

- [Handling MySQL datetimes and timestamps in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323618/handling-mysql-datetimes-and-timestamps-in-java/3323870#3323870)

Answer (score 2):

The format operations (`fmt:formatDate and fmt:formatNumber`) default to using `.toString()` if locale is `NULL`, even if an explicit format has no conversions that are locale dependent. Depending on the setup of your appserver there may be no default locale, leaving it `NULL`

Try adding `locale`

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${object.mydate}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" var="mydate" locale="en"/>
<c:out value="${mydate}"/>
```

Comment: Attribute locale invalid for tag formatDate according to TLD...
I try <fmt:setLocale value="en" scope="page"/> but same ("2014-08-21 00:00:00")