# Binding JSF inputText to a HashMap doesn't work

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, dictionary, el

I am trying to bind multiple inputText fields to a `HashMap<Integer, String>`. But it doesn't put any value into the `HashMap`.

Here is the JSF page.

```
<ui:repeat  value="#{questionBean.question.answerCollection}" var="answer">                
    <h:inputText  value="#{questionBean.newComments[answer.answerId]}"></h:inputText>
    <br/>
    <h:commandButton value="Add Comment">
                    <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{questionBean.makeComment(answer)}"></f:ajax>
    </h:commandButton>
</ui:repeat>
```

Here is related part of the backing bean.

```
private Map<Integer, String> newComments = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
...

public void makeComment(Answers answer) throws Exception {
    String username = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser();

    Users user = userFacade.getUserByUsername(username);

    Comments comment = new Comments();

    for(Integer key: newComments.keySet()){
        throw new Exception("Answer ID IS :"+key);
        // It doesn't throw any exception in here.
        // The map is empty.
    }        

    String commentContent = newComments.get(answer.getAnswerId());
    if(commentContent == null){
        throw new Exception("Content Is NULL");
        // It throws exception here.
    }

    comment.setCommentContent(newComments.get(answer.getAnswerId()));
    comment.setDateCreated(new java.sql.Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));
    comment.setAnswerId(answer);
    comment.setUserId(user);
    commentFacade.create(comment);
}
```

What may be wrong in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main mistake is that the `<f:ajax>` isn't being told to process the input field as well. Its `execute` event defaults to `@this`, which means "the current component". Thus with this construct, only the `<h:commandButton>` would be processed (i.e. its action would be decoded, queued and invoked).

So, fix it accordingly by explicitly telling it to process the entire form:

```
<f:ajax execute="@form" ... />
```

The next (potential) mistake is EL implementation dependent, but as of now all of them doesn't support generics. A `Map<K, V>` would simply be seen as `Map` without any implicit/automatic conversion of keys and values. In EL, numeric values are implicitly interpreted as `Long`. In your particular case, the `Map` would be filled with `Long` keys instead of `Integer` keys, potentially causing `ClassCastException` while iterating over it. If you fix the model accordingly to use `Long` instead of `Integer`, then this problem should be solved as well.

private Map newComments = new HashMap();

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, using `java.sql.*` models in frontend side is a terribly bad idea. Use it in database side instead.

Comment: Could you give a short explanation or referrence why using Java.sql.Date is such a bad idea? Thank you

Comment: @stg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323618/handling-mysql-datetimes-and-timestamps-in-java Using persistence layer specific classes in the model is tight-coupling. Just use `java.util.Date` all the time and only convert it at exactly the point you absolutely need to do the conversion (i.e. exactly when you need to do `preparedStatement.setDate()`). Besides, JSF calendar/datepicker components do also not support `java.sql.*` date/time classes. They would attempt to set an instance of `java.util.Date` in model, with property not found exceptions as consequence.