# How to retrive timestamp values from mysql DB

Tags: java, mysql

I have a java MVC architecture(Simple MVC not used any Framework) which will connect to DB & the query will fetch the time-stamp value which is in the MySQL DB.But I am not getting the expected output it is throwing

**Value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp**
For this exception ,I Googled many of them said to add parameters in the DB URL i tried that

"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/acc_dev_db?**connectTimeout=100000&autoReconnect=true&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull**"

After adding this I am getting o/p as null

Here is my code :

```
public HeartBeatBean getHBDetails(Double nidev) throws SQLException
 {  
     HeartBeatBean hbBean = null;  
     if(nidev > 0)
     {  
         pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT nidevid,hbtimestamp  FROM nidhb where nidevid=? ORDER  BY nidhbid");


   try {  
            pstmt.setDouble(1, nidev);
            rs = pstmt.executeQuery(); 
            if(rs.next())
            {  
                hbBean = new HeartBeatBean();  
                rs.getTimestamp("hbtimestamp");
                System.out.println(rs.getTimestamp("hbtimestamp"));
                hbBean.setHbtimestamp(rs.getTimestamp("hbtimestamp"));


            }  

        } 
            catch (SQLException ex)
            {  
                System.err.println(ex.getMessage());  
            }
```

Comment: Timestamp timestamp = resultSet.getTimestamp("ts");              http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323618/handling-mysql-datetimes-and-timestamps-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323618/handling-mysql-datetimes-and-timestamps-in-java

Comment: Still getting same error sir

Comment: I tried all the stuff But still facing same error