# How to parse this kind of date time to sql datetime in java?

Tags: java, parsing, datetime, twitter

I am trying to get tweet information from twitter in json format. And store them into a database, but the problem is twitter's date format. I get date as string

```
String time = ((JSONObject)array.get(i)).get("created_at").toString();
```

It prints

```
 Mon Aug 10 07:34:06 +0000 2015
```

for example. But of course i cannot store that in this format into database, how can i convert that  to Mysql date time in java ? 
Any help is appreciated

Comment: what is ur expected format ( **Mysql date time format** )?

Comment: What *exactly* is returned by call to `get( "created_at" )`?

Comment: @Pitchers  yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm:ss

Comment: @BasilBourque it returns me this date > Mon Aug 10 07:34:06 +0000 2015

Comment: @BasilBourque and i need to convert that to 2015-08-10 07:34:06

Comment: @Toolbox I doubt the call to get is returning a String because why would you call `toString` on a String? So I'll ask again, ***exactly*** what class is the object returned by the call to `get("created_at")`? I ask because that is the key to a better solution.

Comment: @BasilBourque thanks a lot for paying attention to my question, I found a solution, if you are interested to see, i posted it as answer with code betics.  there you can see the answer of your question too.

Comment: @Toolbox I asked what object type you were getting because I suspect you already had a date object in hand, so you didn't need to call toString, do you didn't need to parse. **Parsing a string of a date to get a date** is a silly waste of time if you could simply have used the original date in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Get the string:

```
String time = "Mon Aug 10 07:34:06 +0000 2015";
```

Create a [`DateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse this `String`

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
```

And parse the string (`ParseException` may be thrown)

```
DateTime date = df.parse(time);
```

**UPDATE**:
in order to [store in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323618/handling-mysql-datetimes-and-timestamps-in-java) format `DateTime`, I use Java `Timestamp`.

```
// get the date
Date date = (Date)((JSONObject)array.get(i)).get("created_at");
// convert to timestamp
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
```

After you can send it to your database to persist.

Comment: that throws exception unparseable date :/

Comment: you can do `Date date = (Date)((JSONObject)array.get(i)).get("created_at");` ??

Comment: so you must convert this date to `Timestamp` and send it to your database.

Comment: String time = ((JSONObject)array.get(i)).get("created_at").toString();  
                
                 java.util.Date date = new Date(time);
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                String format = formatter.format(date);
                System.out.println(format);

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DateFormat.parse(String s)`

[Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys, i solved my problem like that ;

```html
String time = ((JSONObject)array.get(i)).get("created_at").toString();
java.util.Date date = new Date(time);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String format = formatter.format(date);
System.out.println(format);
```