# @DeleteMapping not deleting database row when timestamps are used as request parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, backend

I have created a delete request utilizing Spring Data JPA with the controller method below. When I hit this endpoint through Postman/Insomnia using a `reason` string found in the database table, `localhost:8088/123456789/timeoff?reason=test`, the delete request works as expected, deleting the row with the specified reason and returning the successful response status.

**Working Controller Method:**

```
@CrossOrigin
@DeleteMapping(value = "/{advisor:[0-9]{0,19}}/timeoff")
protected PostResponse deleteAdvisorTimeoffByReason(@PathVariable Long advisor, @RequestParam String reason) {
    PostResponse response = new PostResponse();

    advisorTimeoffService.deleteAdvisorTimeoffByReason(reason);

    response.setSuccessful(true);
    response.setStatus(200);
    response.setMessage("Successfully deleted Advisor time off.");

    return response;
}
```

However, I run into issues when I try to create a delete request using Timestamp request parameters. When I make another Postman/Insomnia request `localhost:8088/123456789/timeoff?datetimeStart=2021-12-25 13:00:00&datetimeEnd=2021-10-25 14:00:00`, I once again get a successful response, but the row corresponding to the datetimeStart and datetimeEnd timestamps is not deleted from the database.

**Non-Working Controller:**

```
@CrossOrigin
@DeleteMapping(value = "/{advisor:[0-9]{0,19}}/timeoff")
protected PostResponse deleteAdvisorTimeoffByDate(@PathVariable Long advisor, @RequestParam Timestamp datetimeStart, @RequestParam Timestamp datetimeEnd) {
    PostResponse response = new PostResponse();

    advisorTimeoffService.deleteAdvisorTimeoffByDate(advisor, datetimeStart, datetimeEnd);

    response.setSuccessful(true);
    response.setStatus(200);
    response.setMessage("Successfully deleted Advisor time off.");

    return response;
}
```

**Entity**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADVISOR_TIMEOFF", schema = "OSS")
@IdClass(AdvisorTimeoffPK.class)
public class AdvisorTimeoff {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ADVISOR")
    private long advisor;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "DATETIME_START")
    private Timestamp datetimeStart;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "DATETIME_END")
    private Timestamp datetimeEnd;

    @Column(name = "REASON")
    private String reason;

    @Column(name = "RECUR")
    private boolean recur;

    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "DATETIME_CREATED")
    private Timestamp datetimeCreated;

    @Column(name = "DATETIME_MODIFIED")
    private Timestamp datetimeModified;

    //equals() and hashCode() methods
}
```

**JPA Repository:**

```
public interface AdvisorTimeoffRepository extends CrudRepository<AdvisorTimeoff, AdvisorTimeoffPK> {

    //Delete by reason
    @Transactional
    void deleteAdvisorTimeoffByAdvisorAndReason(Long advisor, String reason);

    //Delete by dates
    @Transactional
    void deleteAdvisorTimeoffByAdvisorAndDatetimeStartAndDatetimeEnd(Long advisor, Timestamp datetimeStart, Timestamp datetimeEnd);
}
```

**Service Class:**

```
public interface AdvisorTimeoffService {

    void deleteAdvisorTimeoffByReason(Long advisor, String reason);

    void deleteAdvisorTimeoffByDate(Long advisor, Timestamp datetimeStart, Timestamp datetimeEnd);

}
```

**Implementation:**

```
@Service
public class AdvisorTimeoffImpl implements AdvisorTimeoffService {

    @Autowired
    private AdvisorTimeoffRepository advisorTimeoffRepository;


    @Override
    public void deleteAdvisorTimeoffByReason(Long advisor, String reason) {
        advisorTimeoffRepository.deleteAdvisorTimeoffByAdvisorAndReason(advisor, reason);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAdvisorTimeoffByDates(Long advisor, Timestamp datetimeStart, Timestamp datetimeEnd) {
        advisorTimeoffRepository.deleteAdvisorTimeoffByAdvisorAndDatetimeStartAndDatetimeEnd(advisor, datetimeStart, datetimeEnd);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why the first request would work, but not the second one, given the code that I wrote for both is nearly identical. Any direction would be appreciated!

Comment: you need to show us what your repository method looks like

Comment: Please add the code for `deleteAdvisorTimeoff` method and all other relevant methods that are called within that one. Thanks!

Comment: @JoãoDias I've updated the post to include additional relevant methods!

Comment: Can you please also add `AdvisorTimeoff`? Thanks!

Comment: @JoãoDias Done!

Comment: Everything looks good code-wise, so the missing piece must be your data. You need to check two things: 1. Guarantee that both `2021-10-25 14:00:00` and `2021-12-25 13:00:00` are correctly deserialized to a `Timestamp` object. 2. If they do, then confirm that those values are in fact in your database.

Comment: Additionally, you may want to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323618/handling-mysql-datetimes-and-timestamps-in-java.

Comment: @JoãoDias Thanks for your insight, I really appreciate it. It looks like I have an issue involving time zones in my request parameters, and I need to convert everything to UTC to make the database happy.

Comment: That might be it indeed.