# Java Date -> to MySql Time

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a Date format in java that I need to save as a Time format in MySQL.  Is there a way to just get the time part from the date?  I know Dat.gettime() that returns a long but I just need the Time in MySql

Any suggestions...

Thx all ..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2400955/248903

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a PreparedStatement together with a `java.sql.Time` object created from your `java.util.Date` should work:

```
java.util.Date myDate = ....
java.sql.Time theTime = new java.sql.Time(myDate.getTime());
PreparedStatement pstmt = ...
pstmt.setTime(1, theTime);
```

Comment: Correct Answer, but a couple caveats: (A) This produces a time-of-day in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) rather than [a particular time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), which may or may not be what you want. (B) The [`java.sql.Time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html) class is now legacy, supplanted by the [`java.time.LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) class as of [JDBC 4.2](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr221/index2.html) and later.

Answer (score 0):

Use the java.sql.Date to build a SQL Date.

```
long d = date.getTime();
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use SimpleDateFormat to format the Time fields of your date:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss" );
String time = sdf.format (  yourDate  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the JDBC driver, it could omit the time portion of the date, better use java.sql.Timestamp.

```
java.sql.Timestamp mysqlDate = new java.sql.Timestamp( javaDate.getTime() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Get Date + Time Mysql

```
ResultSet rs=....;

Date tg = new Date(rs.getTimestamp("column datetime").getTime());
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm aaa");

String val = sdf.format(tg);
```

Answer (score 0):

When exchanging data with a database, use appropriate date types and objects. Do not use mere strings or integers instead of legitimate types/classes.

## java.time

The **modern approach uses java.time** classes. With a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) complying with JDBC 4.2 or later, you can omit the use of `java.sql.Time` class, and just use `java.time.LocalTime` directly.

The legacy class [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) represents a date and a time-of-day in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Convert to a modern java.time class (`Instant`), assign a time zone through which you want to view the value, and extract the time-of-day.

To convert, call new methods added to the old legacy classes.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

Assign a time zone.

The time zone is *crucial*. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  // Or "Asia/Kolkata", or "Pacific/Auckland", etc.
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Extract the time-of-day without a date.

```
LocalTime lt = zdt.toLocalTime() ;
```

Pass into your `PreparedStatement` by calling `setObject`.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_ ( time_of_day_ ) VALUES ( ? ) ; " ;
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement( sql ) ;
ps.setObject( 1 , lt ) ;  // Call `setObject` to pass a java.time object directly without converting into `java.sql.*` type.
int rows = ps.executeUpdate() ;
```

Fetch data in a similar manner, calling `ResultSet::getObject`.

```
LocalTime lt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalTime.class ) ;
```