# com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: 'Mon Feb 11 00:00:00 IST 2013' for column 'INVOICE_DATE' at row 1

Tags: java, mysql, date, jdbc

I've an excel sheet `Book.xls` like below:

```
   _________________________________________________________________
   |                                         |                      |
   |        INVOICE                          |        INVOICE_DATE  |
   |_________________________________________|______________________|
   |                                         |                      |
   |C-EDGE/SBI//BHO/(ATM)-013/2012–2013      |   11-Feb-2013        |
   |_________________________________________|______________________|
   |C-EDGE/SBI//BANG/(ATM)-013/2012–2013     |   13-Aug-2014        |
   |_________________________________________|______________________|
```

I am trying to insert Date from excel to MySQL table as below:

```
try {
    POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(input);
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    Row row;
    for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
        row = sheet.getRow(i);
        RichTextString CEDGE_INVOICE_NUMBER = row.getCell(0).getRichStringCellValue();
        Date INVOICE_DATE = row.getCell(1).getDateCellValue();
        System.out.println(INVOICE_DATE);
        String sql = "INSERT INTO tablename VALUES('" + CEDGE_INVOICE_NUMBER + "','" + INVOICE_DATE + "')";
        pstm = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstm.execute();
        System.out.println("Import rows " + i);
    }
    con.commit();
    pstm.close();
    con.close();
    input.close();
    System.out.println("Success import excel to mysql table");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    System.out.println(ioe);
}
```

However, I got an exception:

> "com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation:
>    Incorrect datetime value: 'Mon Feb 11 00:00:00 IST 2013' for
>    column 'INVOICE_DATE' at row 1".

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Try to parse `INVOICE_DATE` which your mysql database support.`String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(row.getCell(1).getDateCellValue());`

Comment: Have a look here:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400955/how-to-store-java-date-to-mysql-datetime

Answer (score 1):

When using `PreparedStatement`, use `?` placeholders for values; then you can use `setDate` method of the `PreparedStatemet`. E.g. in your code:

```
String sql ="INSERT INTO tablename VALUES(?,?)";
pstm = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);

for(int i=1; i<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){
    row = sheet.getRow(i);
    RichTextString CEDGE_INVOICE_NUMBER = row.getCell(0).getRichStringCellValue();
    String stringInvoiceNumber = ... // convert RichTextString to normal String

    Date INVOICE_DATE = row.getCell(1).getDateCellValue();
    // you have to use java.sql.Date instead of java.util.Date in PreparedStatement
    java.sql.Date sqlInvoiceDate = new java.sql.Date(INVOICE_DATE.getTime());

    pstm.setString(1, stringInvoiceNumber);
    pstm.setDate(2, sqlInvoiceDate);

    pstm.execute();

    ...    
}
```

See e.g. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/preparedstatement.html for more info.

Comment: Hello Jozef Thank you for your reply. If I want import only month and year what is the code. In my excel file had another column i.e., INVOICE_FOR MONTH and values are "Jan-2013". How can i import this month and year in MYSQL table.

Comment: And how does your mySQL table look like? Ideally add its `CREATE TABLE` statement to your question.

Comment: Hello Mr. Jozef I got a null pointer exception when my excel row is empty. It means the sheet has 190 rows in between those rows some are empty. In that situation I got java.lang.NullPointerException. Please help me this is my code.

Comment: @Lee001 I don't see any java code in your comment. Try to paste it e.g. in  http://chopapp.com/ (or http://pastebin.com/) and post a link here.

Comment: String sql ="INSERT INTO penality VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                       pstm = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
                       
                       
                       
                       for(int i=1; i<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){
                         row = sheet.getRow(i);
                         
                         RichTextString CEDGE_INVOICE_NUMBER = row.getCell(0).getRichStringCellValue();
                         String stringInvoiceNumber = "'"+CEDGE_INVOICE_NUMBER+"'";

Comment: Date INVOICE_DATE = row.getCell(1).getDateCellValue();
                         
java.sql.Date sqlInvoiceDate = new 
                         java.sql.Date(INVOICE_DATE.getTime());
String INVOICE_FOR_MONTH=new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-yyyy").format(row.getCell(2).getDateCellValue());
    String stringInvoiceForMonth=INVOICE_FOR_MONTH;

Comment: String LHO=row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue();
                         double AMOUNT_BEFORE_STAX=(double) row.getCell(4).getNumericCellValue();
                         double S_TAX=(double) row.getCell(5).getNumericCellValue();
                         double TOTAL_AMOUNT=(double) row.getCell(6).getNumericCellValue();
                         double PENALITY=(double) row.getCell(7).getNumericCellValue();
                         double RECEIVED_AMOUNT=(double) row.getCell(8).getNumericCellValue();
                         String REMARKS=row.getCell(9).getStringCellValue();

Comment: pstm.setString(1, stringInvoiceNumber);
                         pstm.setDate(2, sqlInvoiceDate);
                         pstm.setString(3,stringInvoiceForMonth);
                         pstm.setString(4,LHO);
                         pstm.setDouble(5,AMOUNT_BEFORE_STAX);
                         pstm.setDouble(6,S_TAX);
                         pstm.setDouble(7,TOTAL_AMOUNT);
                         pstm.setDouble(8,PENALITY);
                         pstm.setDouble(9,RECEIVED_AMOUNT);
                         pstm.setString(10, REMARKS);

                         pstm.execute();

Comment: This is the logic to import excel data into mysql table. But here I got null pointer exception when the excel row is empty.

Comment: that means excel is like this                                                                          _____________________________________________
              |            In_No                |           In_Date              |
              |__________________ |__________________ |
              |         TS45628             |        23-Feb-2014         |
              |__________________ |___________________|
              |                                     |       18-Jun-2014           |   
              |__________________ | __________________|

Comment: In this excel had one empty cell. So, here I got "NullPointerException". Help me .

Comment: @Lee001 Would you mind to use some pasting service? The code in comments is **very hard** to read.

Comment: Hi, Mr.Jozef, I want to display that above inserted data in jsp. Could you please give me code for retrieve data using struts2.