# How to save a "timestamp" in the database with JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I have an application that already exists and I have to add a column in the database with JPA to save a "Timestamp" (complete date with time) and then make an endpoint to receive this "Timestamp" but I'm new to Java and programming and I'm not sure how to do it. I tried to do like this:

Service:

```
@Column(name="timeStamp", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
public Date getTimeStamp() {
    return timeStamp;
}

public void setTimeStamp(Date timeStamp) {
    this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
}
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping(
    value = "/{date}",
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
)
public ResponseEntity<?> testDate(@RequestParam Timestamp date){
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(VisitantService.getTimeStamp());
}
```

But it keeps giving error.

Comment: You can use Date data type, suppose your column name is UPDATED_DATETIME, then you have to add a member variable which will be mapped to that column like  @Column(name = "UPDATED_DATETIME")
private Date updatedDateTime;// generate getter and setter and then you have to set you value in this from where you are going to save your dataobject

Comment: You can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400955/how-to-store-java-date-to-mysql-datetime-with-jpa

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Instant` to capture the date and time. It is compatible with JPA. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html